# Accidentally deleted files on Windows 7 partition when upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: data-recovery

I accidentally lost all my data on the hard drive. I thought only `C:` drive would be erased.

I am now on Ubuntu 16.04. Is there any way to resolve this in an easy manner?

Comment: Most data may be recoverered but sadly this will be much harder than it was to lose them.

Comment: **Ubantu** never dies http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15684/ubuntu-misspellings

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not do anything that will write to the hard drive - you will potentially lose data permanently that way.

There's a good article here that might help you out:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

However, there's no guarantee of getting data back, but it is possible that you can get at least some.

Comment: This can arguable not be considered an answer. Read more here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259